# How do you free() a buffer pointer in a secondary thread, if the pointer was created with malloc() in the main thread?

Tags: c, multithreading, pointers, malloc, free

I am trying to implement a solution based partly on the discussions below. Basically, I want to `malloc()` in the main thread and `free()` in a secondary thread.  The discussions linked deal with LabWindows, but I think my question is more aimed at C programmers in general.

> [LabWindows: implementing thread safe queues that can handle string
>   elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18277407/labwindows-implementing-thread-safe-queues-that-can-handle-string-elements)
>
> [How to use a thread safe queue to store strings](https://forums.ni.com/t5/LabWindows-CVI/How-to-use-a-thread-safe-queue-to-store-strings/td-p/319335?profile.language=en)

I create a pointer to char in the main thread and allocate storage using `malloc()`.  I copy some data into the storage, and assign the pointer to an array element (`CmtWriteTSQData` expects an array).  This array gets passed to a thread safe queue.

In a secondary thread, the thread safe queue is read.  The data is assigned to a new array.

**How do I free the memory allocated within the secondary thread, as the pointer variable is no longer in scope?**

Can I just call `free()` on the array element?  Or do I need to create another pointer to char in the secondary thread, copy the array element to it, and then call `free()` on the pointer?

There doesn't appear to be a return value with `free()`, so I can't figure out how to ensure the call succeeds.

```
// Main thread
char *ptr = NULL;
char *array1[1] = {0};

ptr = (char *) malloc (3 * sizeof (char));

strcpy (ptr, "hi");

array1[0] = ptr;

CmtWriteTSQData (queue, array1, 1, 0 NULL);
```

```
// Secondary thread
char *array2[1] = {0};

CmtReadTSQData (queue, array2, 1, 0, 0);

printf ("%s", array2[0]);  // Prints "hi"

free (array2[0]);  // Does this work?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is yes.

When you call `malloc()`, you are asking the operating system to give you a chunk of usable memory of some minimum size, and the operating system responds by passing you a pointer, which is just an integer representing the virtual address of that chunk of memory.

When a program has multiple threads, this means that several lightweight processes are sharing the same virtual address space, which means if there are several copies of some valid pointer among several threads of the same process, then they must all point to the same memory location.

The operating system does not care which thread asked for the memory, and it does not care which thread gives it back. When `malloc()` returns a pointer in a process, all of the threads in that process may use it, and when one of the threads `free()`s that pointer, that memory location becomes invalid for all threads in the process.

I don't know how the functions `CmtWriteTSQData()` and `CmtReadTSQData()` behave, but as long as `printf("%p\n",ptr)` in `main` and `printf("%p\n",array2[0])` in the secondary thread produce the same hex value, your code is good.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I would add that the multuthreaded app must be linked with a thread-safe malloc library.  This is not always guaranteed - some embedded development environments have both thread safe and unsafe libraries available, (the unsafe ones being a bit faster 'cos no locking), so in that particular case you need to take extra care.  Still a good answer though - a chance to upvote something for a change:)

Comment: @Willis Thanks to your suggestion, I used the `%p` format specifier to confirm the pointer being freed matched the pointer from `malloc()`.